# C# Triangle numbers optimization

Tags: c#, optimization, divider

The task is to find a triangle number which has at least 500 divisors.

For example 28 has 6 divisors: `1,2,4,7,14,28`

My code works for up to 200 divisors, but for 500 it runs forever...

Is there any way to optimize the code. For instance I thought of dynamic optimization and memoization, but couldn't find a way to do it?

```
            int sum = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            int count = 1;

            bool isTrue = true;
            while (isTrue)
            {
                counter = 0;
                sum += count;

                for (int j = 1; j <= sum; j++)
                {
                    if (sum % j == 0)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == 500)
                        {
                            isTrue = false;
                            Console.WriteLine("Triangle number: {0}", sum);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                count++;
            }            
            Console.WriteLine("Number of divisors: {0}", counter);
```

Comment: the easiest method to find this number is to multiply numbers from 1 to 500.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov that would not be a triangle number

Comment: that's some quadratic runtime you've got there.  maybe even bigger than quadratic

Comment: in-fact, I think it's cubic

Comment: what is a triangle number by the way?

Comment: @SamIam 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 .... upto n

Comment: seems that you can also get the n th triangular number by using this formula: (n * (n + 1)) / 2. Seen it on wikipedia

Comment: In effect the question becomes a case of finding consecutive two numbers which have 500 factors between them.

Comment: Do you need to find *any* number that is a triangle number with more than 500 divisors, or the *smallest* triangle number with that property?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Well, from a mathematical point of view, you can just provide the brute force solution.  Coming up with an algorithm that can be executed efficiently seems like more of a programing problem (with a bit of a mathematical basis).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Unless they're deleted, I don't see any banter with the OP, you're just talking to other readers who got more (or guessed more) from the OP's post.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I can see deleted answers, and there are no comments from the OP there, or any other deleted answers.  Just other readers of the question.

Comment: Sorry guys that I didn't provide more detailed explanation... maybe I didn't want you to recognize that the exercise is from Project Euler, thus quote me the solution they provide (as it happened eventually below)... instead I wanted to help me optimize my code... And yes, I needed to find the smallest triangle number that has 500 divisors. Now code is optimized.

Comment: @Servy: Maybe I just know too much math. It took me less than 10 minutes to work out and prove closed form solutions for both T-number and M-number, and OP made no mention of needing a Minimum solution.

Comment: @Todo: First off, it was immediately obvious that it was an Euler problem. Second, why would you want to deceive the people you're asking for help?  If you wanted hints because you wanted to solve the puzzle yourself then don't ask for a solution. Say "I'm working on Euler #12 and I could use a hand optimizing this code".

Comment: @Todo: Please don't second guess us. If you had told us that it was a project Euler problem and you just wanted a hint on where to look next, we would not have wasted our time guessing what degree of assistance you needed/desired. You failed to mention that a minimal solution was desired, so I gave a (vastly bigger than minimal) closed form solution that met the problemas tated. Someone downvoted it so I removed it.

Comment: @EricLippert that is what he asked for

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: Please, stop blaming me, as I think I wrote enough information for what I was after. Read again my first sentence "triangle number which has at least 500 divisors" meaning that if I find triangle number  with 500 divisors, it's all good. There is no need to explain where the task comes from... Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Ignore the fact that the number is a triangle number. If you can solve this problem quickly:

- given any number n, determine the number of divisors it has

then obviously you can solve Euler #12 quickly. Just list the triangle numbers, which are easy to calculate, determine the number of divisors of each, and stop when you get a result 500 or larger.

So how do you determine the number of divisors quickly?  As you've discovered, when the numbers get big, it's a lot of work.

Here's a hint. Suppose you already have the *prime factorization*. Let's pick a number, say, 196.  Factorize that into prime numbers:

```
196 = 2 x 2 x 7 x 7
```

I can tell you just by glancing at the factorization that 196 has *nine divisors*. How?

Because any divisor of 196 is of the form:

```
(1, 2 or 2x2) x (1, 7 or 7x7)
```

So obviously there are nine possible combinations:

```
1 x 1
1 x 7
1 x 7 x 7
2 x 1
2 x 7
2 x 7 x 7
2 x 2 x 1
2 x 2 x 7
2 x 2 x 7 x 7
```

Pick another number. 200, lets say.  Thats 2 x 2 x 2 x 5 x 5.  So there are *twelve* possibilities:

```
1 x 1
1 x 5
1 x 5 x 5
2 x 1
2 x 5
...
2 x 2 x 2 x 5 x 5
```

See the pattern?  You take the prime factorization, group them by prime, and count how many are in each group. Then you add one to each of those numbers and multiply them together.  Again, in 200 there are *three* twos and *two* fives in the prime factorization. Add one to each: *four* and *three*. Multiply them together: *twelve*.  That's how many divisors there are.

So you can find the number of divisors very quickly *if you know the prime factorization*.  We have reduced the divisor problem to a much easier problem: **Can you figure out how to produce a prime factorization quickly?**

Comment: Hmm, I got the last part i.e: "Add one to each: four and three. Multiply them together: twelve...", but I couldn't get that part: "(1, 2 or 2x2) x (1, 7 or 7x7)". Also what about number such as 197? Do you first divide it on 2/3/5/7 to check if it's prime or not?

Comment: @Todo: Figuring out how to make a prime factorization is left up to you; you're going to need to know how to do that to solve other Euler problems.  To address your question: Do you not see why any divisor of 196 has to have the form (1, 2 or 2 x 2) x (1, 7 or 7 x 7) ?  Think about it this way. Suppose there was a divisor of 196 that was *not* of that form. What would its prime factors be?

Comment: @Todo: Now, you might say, well, suppose there were some *second* prime factorization, a factorization *other* than 2 x 2 x 7 x 7,  that *also* multiplied to 196. Maybe one of the prime factors is of that *other* form. **That cannot happen.** Make sure you understand this, because it is, I kid you not, **The Fundamental Theorem Of Arithmetic**: every integer has a *unique* prime factorization.

Comment: I read about Theorem Of Arithmetic in Wikipedia and it put light on my understanding, especially that part: **"every integer greater than 1 is either prime itself or is the product of prime numbers"** Honestly I didn't know that fact and it would certainly  help me in future. Thank you!

Comment: @Todo: Excellent! Project Euler really shows you how *the primes are the bricks from which the rest of the numbers are built*. Understand those bricks and you'll be able to build a lot of interesting stuff.

Answer (score 2):

here are some optimizations I'll just throw out there for you.

the easiest thing is to change

```
for (int j = 1; j <= sum; j++)
{
    if (sum % j == 0)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 500)
        {
            isTrue = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Triangle number: {0}", sum);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

if you've found 1 divisor, you've found 2 divisors, so change it to

```
for (int j = 1; j <= sum; j++)
{
    if (sum % j == 0)
    {
        if(sum/j < j)
            break;
        else if(sum/j == j)
            counter++;
        else
            counter +=2;

        if (counter == 500)
        {
            isTrue = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Triangle number: {0}", sum);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

this will reduce the runtime a lot, but it will still take a long time.

---

another optimization you can do is to not start checking form `sum` but calculate the smallest number that has 500 divisors.

and then you can find the largest triangle number after that, and start from there.

---

If you can figure something else special about the nature of this problem, than it is possible for you to reduce the runtime by a whole lot.

Comment: Wow, the if/else if/else rows you added to my code make significant difference and solve the task for less than one second!!! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I don't understand how your second technique works. You take a number with a few hundred prime factors, so it will have 2^a few hundred divisors, not 500 divisors. Why is the next largest triangle number after that number guaranteed to have 500 divisors?

Comment: @EricLippert  you're right, it will have more than 500 divisors.  I've removed my lame attempt at actually calculating that number

Comment: @EricLippert the thinking was that if you could somehow find the smallest number with 500 divisors, than all numbers less than that number will not be the right number, and you'll be wasting your time testing them

Comment: Ah, now that's a good idea, but you need to actually know that you've found the smallest (if you're seeking the smallest triangle number with 500 or more divisors).  2 x 3 x 5 x 7 x 11 x 13 x 17 x 19 x 23 has 512 divisors, but you can get smaller than that. 8 x 3 x 5 x 7 x 11 x 13 x 17 x 19 also has 512 divisors. Can you get even smaller?

Comment: @EricLippert Of course you can: 3 x 3 x 3 < 3 x 19, and 8 x 16 < 8 x 17, so 128 x 27 x 5 x 7 x 11 x 13 is smaller.

Comment: @JeffreySax: Is that the smallest?

Comment: I've got 64 x 9 x 25 x 7 x 11 x 13 (504 divisors). Not convinced it's smallest, but it's under @JeffreySax.

Comment: @EricLippert Making use of the fact that 63<64 but 8 x 63 = 504 > 500, we get that 2^6 x 3^2 x 5^2 x 7 x 11 x 13 = 14414400 has more than 500 divisors. I did a quick brute force check and that is the smallest one.

Answer (score 1):

The number of divisors of a number is the product of the powers of the prime factors plus one. For example: `28 = 2^2*7^1`, so the # of divisors is `(2+1)*(1+1) = 6`.

This means that, if you want many divisors compared to the size of the number, you don't want any one prime to occur too often. Put another way: it is likely that the smallest triangular number with at least 500 divisors is the product of small powers of small primes.

So, instead of checking every number to see if it divides the triangular number, go through a list of the smallest primes, and see how often each one occurs in the prime factorization. Then use the formula above to compute the number of divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Take these steps:

1.) Calculate the first log(2, 499) prime numbers (not 500, as 1 is counted as a divisor if I am nit mistaken despite the fact that it is not prime, as it has only one divisor). There are many solutions out there, but you catch my drift.

2.) A triangle number is of the form of n * (n + 1) / 2, because
1 + 2 + ... + 100 = (1 + 100) + (2 + 99) + ... + (50 + 51) = 101 * 50 = 101 * 100 / 2 = 5050 (as Cauchy solved it when he was an eight-year boy and the teacher punished him with this task).

1 + ... + n = (1 + n) + (2 + n - 1) + ... = n * (n + 1) / 2.

3.) S = prod(first log(2, 499) prime numbers)

4.) Solve the equation of n * (n + 1) / 2 = S and calculate its ceiling. You will have an integer, let's call it m.

5.)

```
while (not(found))
    found = isCorrect(m)
    if (not(found)) then
        m = m + 1
    end if
end while
return m
```

and there you go. Let me know if I was able to help you.

Comment: That (apocryphal) story is usually attributed to the young Gauss.

Comment: And the product of the first 499 prime numbers has 2^499 divisors, not 500 divisors.

Comment: My answer was corrected, I have upvoted your comment, as it helped me improving my answer.

Comment: You can do better than the product of the first nine primes. 2x3x5x7x11x13x19x23 has 512 divisors, but 8x3x5x7x11x13x19 also has 512 divisors and is considerably smaller. Can you find the *smallest* number that has 500 or more divisors?

Comment: log(2, 499) < 9, because 2^9 = 512. So, in worst case we need the product of the first eight primes. I don't know the smallest number with 500 divisors in this moment, if I get some free time I would be glad to find that. So my method is correct, but we could improve that by finding the number you have mentioned. We can find it if we search sequentially between the product of the first 8 primes and the product of the first 9 primes. If we write a program for that, then, in this program we can use the result as a constant.

Comment: By the way, you forgot 17 from 2x3x5x7x11x13x19x23, because 2x3x5x7x11x13x19x23 has only 256 divisors.

Comment: Yes, and you are right in that. Maybe the op could write a separate program, which finds the first natural number with 500 or more divisors and use that as a constant. Maybe we could derive a formula to find the first natural number with n or more divisors, but, honestly, I'm having a deadline and don't have enough time to try that.

Comment: This program would search for the first number which meets the criteria between the product of the first log(2, 499) primes and the product of the first log(2, 499) + 1 primes.

Answer (score 0):

As @EricLippert nad @LajosArpad mentioned, the key idea is to iterate over [triangle numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) only. You can calculate them using the following formula:

> T(n) = n * (n + 1) / 2

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0stya/9T2dU/) which you may find helpful.

```
function generateTriangleNumber(n) {
    return (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
}

function findTriangleNumberWithOver500Divisors() {
    var nextTriangleNum;
    var sqrt;
    for (i = 2;; i++) {
        var factors = [];
        factors[0] = 1;
        nextTriangleNum = generateTriangleNumber(i);
        sqrt = Math.pow(nextTriangleNum, 0.5);
        sqrt = Math.floor(sqrt);
        var j;
        for (j = 2; j <= sqrt; j++) {
            if (nextTriangleNum % j == 0) {
                var quotient = nextTriangleNum / j;
                factors[factors.length] = j;
                factors[factors.length] = quotient;
            }
        }
        factors[factors.length] = nextTriangleNum;
        if (factors.length > 500) {
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(nextTriangleNum);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Incidentally, the first [Google](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=divisors%20of%20triangular%20number) result for `divisors of triangular number` search query gives this :)

[Project Euler 12: Triangle Number with 500 Divisors](http://www.mathblog.dk/triangle-number-with-more-than-500-divisors/)

See if it helps.

**EDIT:** Text from that article:

> The first triangle number with over 500 digits is: 76576500 Solution
>   took 1 ms

Comment: I know it's Project Euler 12 :) But I didn't want to see exactly how it's solved there... I wanted to solve it my way.

Comment: oops... Should i remove the edited part of my post before you read it? :)

Comment: no worries... I won't count it solved until I do it myself :)

Comment: I was not me, but I suppose the down vote is because from Project Euler ask members not to bring out solutions to their problems outside their website :(